# SwiftUI, the button is not showing when the user taps on the Index Card

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this struct in SwiftUI, which is responsible for displaying information on the front and back sides:

```
import SwiftUI

struct IndexCardSides<Front, Back>: View where Front: View, Back: View {
    
    var front: () -> Front
    var back: () -> Back
    
    @State var flipped : Bool = false
    @State var indexCardRotation : Double = 0.0
    @State var textRotation : Double = 0.0
    
    init(@ViewBuilder front: @escaping () -> Front, @ViewBuilder back: @escaping () -> Back) {
        self.front = front
        self.back = back
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if flipped {
                back()
            } else {
                front()
            }
        }
        .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(textRotation), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
        .padding() // Text Padding
        .frame(height: 150)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .overlay {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
                .stroke(Color("BorderColor"), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2))
        }
        .padding() // Rectangles Padding
        .onTapGesture {
            flipIndexCard()
        }
        .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(indexCardRotation), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
    }
    
    func flipIndexCard() {
        
        let animationTime = 0.5
        
        withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: animationTime)) {
            indexCardRotation += 180
        }
        
        withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.001).delay(animationTime / 2)) {
            textRotation += 180
            flipped.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

And also I have this View which I pass the information to the IndexCardSides:

```
import SwiftUI

enum QuizState {
    case SOLUTION_VISIBLE, QUIZ_ACTIVE, QUIZ_FINISHED
}

struct QuizView: View {
    
    @State var learningUnit: LearningUnit
    @State var currentInformationIndex: Int = 0
    @State private var isFlipped : Bool = false
    
    @State var quizState: QuizState = QuizState.QUIZ_ACTIVE
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            IndexCardSides(
                front: {
                    Text(learningUnit.information[currentInformationIndex].part01)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                }, back: {
                    Text(learningUnit.information[currentInformationIndex].part02)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                }
            )
            
            Button(action: {
                if quizState == QuizState.QUIZ_ACTIVE {
                    
                    if currentInformationIndex == learningUnit.information.count - 1 {
                        quizState = QuizState.QUIZ_FINISHED
                    } else {
                        quizState = QuizState.SOLUTION_VISIBLE
                    }
                    
                } else if quizState == QuizState.SOLUTION_VISIBLE {
                    currentInformationIndex = currentInformationIndex + 1
                    quizState = QuizState.QUIZ_ACTIVE
                } else {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
                
            }) {
                if quizState == QuizState.QUIZ_ACTIVE {
                    Label("show solution", systemImage: "eye")
                } else if quizState == QuizState.SOLUTION_VISIBLE {
                    Label("Next", systemImage: "arrow.right")
                } else {
                    Label("Done", systemImage: "checkmark")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Questions")
    }
}
```

What exactly trying to do:

- When the user opens the QuizView, the only thing that should be displayed is the card.
- When the user flips it, a button should be displayed under it called "Next". This button should move the user to the next index card.
- When the user press on the "Next" button, it should disappear and display the next index card.
- The code should keep iterating on the information until it reaches the final one. When the user reaches the last one and flip it, the button should be called "Done" and this will be the `presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`

I tried implementing `.onTapGesture` on the IndexCardSides and print anything to check if it works but nothing new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you never tell your `IndexCardSides` view that it should change.

First of all get rid of those `fliped` vars. Keep the `QuizState` var in your `QuizView` as single source of truth and pass it on to your `IndexCardSides` subview. Observe it inside the subview and trigger the animation.

```
struct IndexCardSides<Front, Back>: View where Front: View, Back: View {
    
    // add this binding for the state
    @Binding var state: QuizState
    
    var front: () -> Front
    var back: () -> Back
    
    @State private var indexCardRotation : Double = 0.0
    @State private var textRotation : Double = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if state == .SOLUTION_VISIBLE {
                back()
            } else {
                front()
            }
        }
        .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(textRotation), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
        .padding() // Text Padding
        .frame(height: 150)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .overlay {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
                .stroke(Color("BorderColor"), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2))
        }
        .padding() // Rectangles Padding
        .onTapGesture {
            flipIndexCard()
        }
        .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(indexCardRotation), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
        //observe changes to the binding and call the flip animation when needed
        .onChange(of: state) { newValue in
            if newValue == .SOLUTION_VISIBLE || newValue == .QUIZ_ACTIVE{
                flipIndexCard()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func flipIndexCard() {
        
        let animationTime = 0.5
        
        withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: animationTime)) {
            indexCardRotation += 180
        }
        
        withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.001).delay(animationTime / 2)) {
            textRotation += 180
        }
    }
}



struct QuizView: View {
    var learningUnit: LearningUnit
    @State var currentInformationIndex: Int = 0
    
    @State var quizState: QuizState = QuizState.QUIZ_ACTIVE
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // pass the state on to the subview
            IndexCardSides(state: $quizState)
            {
                Text(learningUnit.information[currentInformationIndex].part01)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            } back: {
                Text(learningUnit.information[currentInformationIndex].part02)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            }
            
            
            Button(action: {
                if quizState == QuizState.QUIZ_ACTIVE {
                    if currentInformationIndex == learningUnit.information.count - 1 {
                        quizState = QuizState.QUIZ_FINISHED
                    } else {
                        quizState = QuizState.SOLUTION_VISIBLE
                    }
                } else if quizState == QuizState.SOLUTION_VISIBLE {
                    currentInformationIndex = currentInformationIndex + 1
                    quizState = QuizState.QUIZ_ACTIVE
                } else {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
                
            }) {
                if quizState == QuizState.QUIZ_ACTIVE {
                    Label("show solution", systemImage: "eye")
                } else if quizState == QuizState.SOLUTION_VISIBLE {
                    Label("Next", systemImage: "arrow.right")
                } else {
                    Label("Done", systemImage: "checkmark")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Questions")
    }
}
```